AWS Ubuntu 24 - Module snd-aloop not found in directory
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 and I am not able to use Alsa with it. I am trying to create a loopback device but I receive the following message.
sudo modprobe snd-aloop
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-aloop not found in directory /lib/modules/6.5.0-1014-aws

Could anyone please help me with this?
